# Insert foreign keys into table A foreach row from table B

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys

I would like to write an `INSERT INTO` script that takes all the rows from table `B` (let's assume table `B` has 300 rows) and uses their ids as foreign key values for some column of table `A` (the one I want to insert to), so I will end up with 300 new rows inserted into table `A`.

How can I achieve that in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO "table_A" ("id_in_table_B")
SELECT
    "id"
FROM "table_B"
```